# Batch convert wav to m4a files using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav, m4a

I'm trying to batch convert thousands of wav files into 96k m4a files on Mac OS Mojave using ffmpeg in the terminal.
I'm trying to use the following code:
`for f in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 96k  “${f%.wav}.m4a”; done`
I'm being given the following error:
**Unable to find a suitable output format for '“file.m4a”'
“file.m4a”: Invalid argument** 
Can anyone help?

Comment: You've somehow entered smart quotes instead of ascii quotes around the output filename. So the smartquotes confuse the command line.

Comment: Yes works perfectly now- I didn't notice that. Many thanks!

Comment: @BenHardy Cool - accept Scott's answer pretty please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smartquotes are treated as part of the filename.
Use plain quotes instead:

`for f in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 96k  "${f%.wav}.m4a"; done`

Answer (score 2):

If you have lots of files to convert, you might want to do that in parallel:

```
find . -name '*. wav' -type f -print0 | parallel -0 ffmpeg -i {}  -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 96k {.}.m4a
```

Check [this doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf) for how to work with `parallel`. If you don't have the tool, install it with `brew install parallel`.

Scott's answer is perfectly fine too. I like `parallel` as it also allows me to easily e.g. modify the name of the output file.